# Use clang for autocompletion in PIC microcontrollers project: need to disable clang warning

Tags: c, autocomplete, clang, pic, microchip

I work with Microchip PIC microcontrollers. I'm trying use clang for autocompletion in Vim.

Of course, I need to make clang to be able to compile my sources. The trouble is that PIC compilers are specific and have some special attributes, for which clang generates warnings.

Here's part of PIC header file:

```
extern __attribute__((space(prog))) int _FBS;
#define _FBS(x) __attribute__((section("__FBS.sec"),space(prog))) int _FBS = (x);
```

Clang generates errors like that:

```
23: warning:
      unknown attribute 'space' ignored [-Wattributes]
extern __attribute__((space(prog))) int _FUID2;
```

How can I disable such warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should disable warnings generated by `-Wattributes`:

```
clang -Wno-attributes
```

Comment: Oh, so easy.. Answer on my question was in the question iteslf. Thank you.